# Convert a string like 2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16 to 2,4-8,10,12,14-16

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I want to convert a string input like 2,3,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16 to 2-3,6-8,10,12,14-16 using java

I tried using the below code

```
        Vector ar=new Vector();

        int lastadded=0;

        String ht="";

        String [] strarray=str.split(",");

        strarray=sortArray(strarray);

        Vector intarray=new Vector();


        for(int i=0;i<strarray.length;i++)
        {

        int temp=1;
            for(int j=1;j<=intarray.size();j++)
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(strarray[i])==Integer.parseInt(intarray.get(j-1).toString()))
                {
                 temp=0;
                }
            }
            if(temp==1)
            {
                intarray.add(Integer.parseInt(strarray[i]));
                ar.add(Integer.parseInt(strarray[i]));
            }


        }


       ht="";
       String strdemo="";
       for(int i=0;i<intarray.size();i++)
       {

            if(ht=="")
            {

                ht=ar.get(i)+"";
        lastadded=i;
            }

        else
         {
             strdemo=(String)ht;
            if(strdemo.length()==ar.get(0).toString().length())
            {

   if(Integer.parseInt(strdemo.substring(0))==Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString())-1)
             {
                 strdemo=strdemo+"-"+ar.get(i);
                 lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                 ht=strdemo;
             }
             else
             {
                 strdemo=strdemo+","+ar.get(i);
                 lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                 ht=strdemo;
             }
            }
            else if(strdemo.length()==3)
            {
                 strdemo=(String)ht;
                 if(Integer.parseInt(strdemo.substring(strdemo.length()-1,strdemo.length()))==Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString())-1)
                 {
                     strdemo=strdemo.substring(0,strdemo.length()-2)+"-"+Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     ht=strdemo;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     strdemo=strdemo+","+Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     ht=strdemo;
                 }
            }//Else IF
            else{
                strdemo=(String)ht;
                int de=1;


                int ddd=lastadded;
                 if(ddd==Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString())-1)
                 {
                      int lastaddedlen=(lastadded+"").length();
                      String symbol=strdemo.substring(strdemo.length()-lastaddedlen-1,strdemo.length()-lastaddedlen);
                     if(symbol.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
                       strdemo=strdemo.substring(0,strdemo.length()-lastaddedlen-1)+"-"+Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     else
                     strdemo=strdemo+"-"+Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     ht=strdemo;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     strdemo=strdemo+","+Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     lastadded=Integer.parseInt(ar.get(i).toString());
                     ht=strdemo;
                 }
            }
    }
}
```

**Here `sortArray` function sorts the array descending and returns**

```
protected static String[] sortArray(String ss[])
    {
        String temp;
        for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<ss.length;j++)
            {
             if(Integer.parseInt(ss[i])<Integer.parseInt(ss[j]))
             {
                temp=ss[i];
                ss[i]=ss[j];
                ss[j]=temp;
             }
            }
        }
        return ss;
    }
```

I am not getting consistant results for some inputs for example for the below case 
`2,3,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16` it gives `2-3,6-8,10,12,14-16` (**which is correct**)
while for `2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16` it gives `2-8,10,12,14-16 (which actually should have been` **2,4-8,10,12,14-16**`)`

Where does the code go inconsistent is what I need to find out..

Comment: whats relation between <2,3,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16>  AND  this collection <2-3,6-8,10,12,14-16 >

Comment: well, it`s easy... 6-8 means that all numbers from 6 to 8 are present in the initial sequence. for example, because 9 is missing, you have 6-8 instead of 6-10 (if 9 was present)

Comment: it clubs the numbers in sequence like `2,3` its a sequence so `2-3` there after the sequence breaks and new sequence `6 to 8` so `6-8` and the two breaks at `10` and `12` and then a continuous sequence from `14 to 16` gives `14-16` resulting in the combined result `2-3,6-8,10,12,14-16`

Comment: Instead of processing the string array, convert it first to integers and then work on the integer array. Now you are doing the same string to integer conversions over and over and it makes your code hard to read.

Comment: BTW, look up "JUnit testing" and the "test first" principle. It would have saved you from this trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty ugly and verbose in Java, but here is a version. Note, it uses StringUtils from Spring at the very end for the trivial but also ugly process of converting a String collection to a comma delimited string.

The key is to use a separate class to model the numeric ranges. Let this class know how to turn itself into a String. Then you won't have so much logic around appending to a StringBuilder.

Also, try to think in terms of collections. This always makes things clearer. The pseudo-code is something like: `String` becomes `List<Integer>` becomes `List<Range>` and finally becomes `String`.

```
public class Ranges {

    // A class that models a range of integers
    public static class Range {
        private int low;
        private int high;

        public Range(int low, int high) {
            this.low = low;
            this.high = high;
        }

        public int getHigh() {
            return high;
        }

        public void setHigh(int high) {
            this.high = high;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (low == high) ? String.valueOf(low) : String.format("%d-%d", low, high);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2,3,6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16";

        // Turn input string into a sorted list of integers
        List<Integer> inputNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String num : input.split(",")) {
            inputNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
        }
        Collections.sort(inputNumbers);

        // Flatten list of integers into a (shorter) list of Ranges
        Range thisRange = null; // the current range being built
        List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<Range>();
        for (Integer number : inputNumbers) {
            if (thisRange != null && number <= thisRange.getHigh() + 1) {
                // if we are already building a range (not null) && this new number is 
                // the old high end of the range + 1, change the high number.
                thisRange.setHigh(number);
            } else {
                // create a new range and add it to the list being built
                thisRange = new Range(number, number);
                ranges.add(thisRange);
            }
        }

        // Join List<String> into a single String
        String result = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(ranges);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for the string input in the ascending order but for a random sequence of string it would give a incorrect result...Can the `sortArray` function I used above be applied here? Eg: `2,5,89,23,6,45,7,8,15,16` gives `2,5,89,23,6,45,7-8,15-16` what i want is `2,5-8,15-16,23,45,89`

Comment: Yes, sort the `List<Integer>` before proceeding with the creation of `List<Range>`. I updated the answer. There is also a problem around de-duplication of numbers in the input. Can you see it?

Comment: Ok thank you perfect.. There wont be any duplication the input I provide so that would not be an issue for me..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. Hope this help.

You have to pass these values 
e.g `int[] a = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12, 14,15,16,18,19,21,22,26};` 
to the following method.

```
public List<String> listIntRange(int[] values)
{
    List<String> intRangeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int first = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int prev = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (values == null || values.length < 1)
        return intRangeList;

    first = prev = values[0];
    int index = 1;
    boolean range = false;
    for(index = 1; index < values.length; index++)
    {
        current = values[index];
        if(current - prev == 1)
        {
            range = true;   
            prev = current;
            continue;
        }

        if(range == true)
        {
            intRangeList.add(first + "-" + prev);
        }
        else
        {
            intRangeList.add("" + first);
        }

        first = current;
        prev = current;
        range = false;

    }

    if(range == true)
    {
        intRangeList.add(first + "-" + current);
    }
    else
    {
        intRangeList.add("" + current);
    }

    return intRangeList;
}
```

Output is as follows, when print out the values from intRangeList:

```
2-8,10,12,14-16,18-19,21-22,26,
```

Please ignore last comma ','.